# Calculate string length in pixel without using TextBlock

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone, string-length

I know a common solution is using `TextBlock`'s `ActualWidth` but sometimes it can causes poor performance. Therefore, I want to know whether it is possible to calculate string length in pixel directly given font and device info in Windows Phone? Something similar to .NET 's `System.Drawing.Graphics.MeasureString()`? Any direction is appreciated.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb464128.aspx this may help you.

Comment: @Jaihind Thanks, but `SpriteFont` doesn't work well with my non-XNA app